# Mysql SUM query not returning the expected result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello I seek help to see what is wrong with my query that is not returning the count (number) of the rows from table consulta where userIDC is equal to userID from table users. and the same operation for userIDC from table asesoria.

```
SELECT c.*, SUM(IF(a.userIDA = c.userID , 1, 0)) AS count_asesoria, SUM(IF(s.userIDC = c.userID , 1, 0)) AS count_consulta
   FROM users as c 
   LEFT JOIN consulta AS s ON s.userIDC = c.userID 
   LEFT JOIN asesoria AS a ON a.userIDA = c.userID
   GROUP BY c.userID DESC
```

rigt now it returs the same result for both `count_asesoria` and `count_consulta`

Table users:

```
userID | Data    |
------------------
3      | content |
```

table consulta

```
userIDC | Data   |
------------------
3      | content |
3      | content |
```

So count_consulta have to return `2`

Comment: Could you show some sample data and what results you expect from your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  most likely cause of your problem is a Cartesian product between the tables in the joins.  The proper solution is to pre-aggregate the results before the query.  Or, use a correlated subquery.  That is probably the easiest method in this case, and might have the best performance:

```
SELECT u.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM consulta c
        WHERE c.userIDC = u.userId
       ) as count_consulta, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM asesoria a
        WHERE a.userIDA = u.userId
       ) as count_asesoria
FROM users u;
```

For optimal performance, you want indexes on `consulta(userIDA)` and `asesoria(userIDA)`.